# Preserving Images In an IBOutletCollection

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch

Here is my code so far:

```
@IBOutlet var Boxes: [UIImageView]!
@IBAction func Success(_ sender: Any) {
    if "" == defaults.value(forKey: "frequency") as? String{
        for box in Boxes{
            if box.image == UIImage(named:"blank.png"){
                box.image = UIImage(named:"Arm.png")
                break
            }
        }
    }
    else if "Twice" == defaults.value(forKey: "frequency") as? String{
        for box in Boxes{
            if box.image == UIImage(named:"Arm1.png"){
                box.image = UIImage(named:"Arm.png")
                break
            }
            else if box.image == UIImage(named:"blank.png"){
                box.image = UIImage(named:"Arm1.png")
                break
            }
        }
        }

}
```

The defaults.value(forKey: frequency) are used to determine how often the user wants to change the grid. How would I create UserDefaults that would restore the images in the grid on app close? (double tap home and swipe up). Are UserDefaults even the right way to do this? I feel like it would be easier, but way messier to create an individual outlet for each UIImageView and saving the state for each one through a giant tree of code. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hacked my way through this.

I ended up looping through the list, and if my conditions were not satisfied, I added one to a variable (starting with 1) to index the list. If I changed the condition, I took the variable and added it to the end of the userDefault. Add a comment if you need any help.

Answer (score 0):

If your images are stored in the bundle (manually added by you and won't be changed) you can save names to the userdefaults instead of saving images. 
Otherwise I would use a database. There is very nice framework [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/). Try it. Also, to store images, it is better to convert them to the Data

Comment: I added all of them (in order) to the bundle. The app functions perfectly as of right now, but I can't figure out how to preserve the chart.

Comment: You can store an array of names to the defaults and use indexes to retrieve images. To get current index of an object in the array use this: for (index, box) in Boxes.enumirated() then you can get an image name by this index like: let imageName = imagesArray[index]. But honestly, I would use realm for it. It is pretty easy to store image as Data and its index as an object in the DB.